# Webpack: Is it possible to evaluate javascript expression at compile time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bundling-and-minification, webpack

I'm trying to setup webpack for my project.
The project is big enough and is provided in multiple languages.
I want each of my entry points to be provided in each language as separate files. My language files are not just plain JSON, but JavaScript instead. So i18n plugin doesn't match my needs.

The solution seems to be similar to i18n plugin:

```
var languages = ['en', 'fr', 'de'];
module.exports = languages.map(function (lang) {
  return {
    name: lang,
    // some other language-dependent config
  }
})
```

Then in some of my scripts I want to require localization file, using environment variable:

```
var lang = ...; // some environment variable, available only at compile time
var l10n = require('./lang/' + lang);
```

But by default webpack tries to store that expression between parentheses assuming to evaluate it later in browser.

So is there a way to tell webpack to evaluate that immediately?

Or maybe someone has a better solution to my problem?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a build tool like Grunt?

Comment: How can a task runner help to solve this problem?

Comment: It sounds like you want to iterate through some Javascript data structure and create separate builds based on that iteration.  A programmable build tool that can read JSON files and can be programmed to do pretty much anything sounds like it could do that.  Just trying to help.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for your help. Yes, the problem is that the project contains a lot of localization files, but a few entry points. So a tool should know where to load which localization file based on require function calls inside project codebase. Will try to dive deeper in writing webpack plugins and loaders. Thanks again :)

Comment: Since you say that the language is at compile time, do you mean you'd like to essentially create different versions of your primary empty point with one for each language?

Comment: @loganfsmyth yes, right. I think I could do this using resolve config section or by writing some plugin/loader.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to use Webpack's `DefinePlugin` to set the language at compile time.

For instance, you could write your require as:

```
var l10n = require('./lang/' + APPLICATION_LANGUAGE);
```

and in your config, have

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    APPLICATION_LANGUAGE: JSON.stringify(lang)
  })
]
```

You can have your build script conditionally set 'lang' based on some parameter or env variable or something.

Comment: Awesome! Don't know how I missed this one. You saved my weekend )))

Comment: Nice and simple solution :+1: